# SQL Select Statement for Time and attendance for a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Anyone can help with this one please? Our attendance system generates the following data:

```
Empid    Department  Timestamp                  Read_ID
3221      IT          2017-01-29 11:12:00.000    1
5565      IT          2017-01-29 12:28:06.000    1
5565      IT          2017-01-29 12:28:07.000    1
3221      IT          2017-01-29 13:12:00.000    2
5565      IT          2017-01-29 13:28:06.000    2
3221      IT          2017-01-30 07:42:15.000    1
3221      IT          2017-01-30 16:16:15.000    2
3221      IT          2017-01-31 09:05:00.000    1
3221      IT          2017-01-31 11:05:00.000    2
3221      IT          2017-01-31 13:20:00.000    1
3221      IT          2017-01-31 16:10:00.000    2
```

Where Read_ID value are :

- `1` = Entry
- `2` = Exit

I'm looking for SQL query to run on MS SQL 2014 that summarize attendance time for each employee on monthly basis, for instance

```
Empid   Department  Year    Month   TotalHours
3221    IT          2017    1       15:24
5565    IT          2017    1       01:00
```

Comment: Not an "answer" per se, but I would recommend that you create a view of this table that has both an "in" and an "out" column.  As long as the definition of said view has a clause to exclude orphaned scans (ins without outs, or outs with a preceding in), then you can use that view to select the sum of (out_time - in_time)

Comment: Why EmpID `5565` has `02:00` hours?

Comment: "I'm looking for SQL query to run on MS SQL 2014" -- so there is no need to tag Oracle, MySQL, SQLite... I removed them for you.

Comment: And what does it mean when someone enters twice in a row without leaving?

Comment: Very interesting question. I assume they mast catch it and clean it out before running the report. Otherwise results might be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I was not sure what time format would satisfy your system, so I put both:

```
SELECT * INTO #Tbl3 FROM (VALUES
(3221,'IT','2017-01-29 11:12:00.000',1),
(5565,'IT','2017-01-29 12:28:06.000',1),
(5565,'IT','2017-01-29 12:28:07.000',1),
(3221,'IT','2017-01-29 13:12:00.000',2),
(5565,'IT','2017-01-29 13:28:06.000',2),
(3221,'IT','2017-01-30 07:42:15.000',1),
(3221,'IT','2017-01-30 16:16:15.000',2),
(3221,'IT','2017-01-31 09:05:00.000',1),
(3221,'IT','2017-01-31 11:05:00.000',2),
(3221,'IT','2017-01-31 13:20:00.000',1),
(3221,'IT','2017-01-31 16:10:00.000',2))
x (Empid,Department,Timestamp,Read_ID)

;With cte as (
    SELECT t1.Empid, t1.Department
        , [Year] = Year(t1.Timestamp)
        , [Month] = Month(t1.Timestamp)
        , Seconds = SUM(DATEDIFF(second, t1.Timestamp, t2.Timestamp))
    FROM #Tbl3 as t1
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT Timestamp = MIN(t.Timestamp) 
        FROM #Tbl3 as t
        WHERE t.Department = t1.Department and t.Empid = t1.Empid
            and t.Timestamp > t1.Timestamp and t.Read_ID = 2
    ) as t2
    WHERE t1.Read_ID = 1
    GROUP BY t1.Empid, t1.Department, Year(t1.Timestamp), Month(t1.Timestamp))
SELECT *, TotalHours = Seconds / 3600., TotalTime =
    RIGHT('0'+CAST(Seconds / 3600 as VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0'+CAST((Seconds % 3600) / 60 as VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
    RIGHT('0'+CAST(Seconds % 60 as VARCHAR),2)
FROM cte;
```

Comment: That script does not process situations with double entry or double leaving. Those cases must be cleared before the report running.

Comment: The multiple entry can be handled using the minimum entry time and the multiple leave can be handled using maximum leave time (modify the internal select statement). The only entry that matters is the first one and the leave that matters is the last one.

Comment: Can be handled, but result can be unpredictable. Would say you've forgot to scan your card leaving a building, then you would have extra 16 hours of "night work". Do not think your employer would like this.

Comment: Short of implanting RFID chips in your employees, you will always have these problems, unless you know what each person's working shift is to limit the range of hours they work.  Also, you have to have a process that handles corrections for the kind of issues you describe.  We've fought this kind of problem where I work and it's a no-win scenario.  Without a work schedule to provide constraints, there will always be outliers like these.  So you need an "exceptions" process and a "Working hours" table for each person (or class of persons). Not the answer you want, but it is the one you need

Comment: I'd better have exception report and let people (managers) handle that. Anyway, everybody must scan their badge entering/leaving a building and if they fail on regular basis that is not computer issue.

Answer (score 2):

This query should give you the result you need. It works by selecting each entries, and joining it with the next exit of the same employee (entries without further exits are ignored) : this gives us the duration of this employee shift. Then results are aggregated and shift durations are sumed in each group.

```
SELECT
    t1.empid, 
    t1.department, 
    YEAR(t1.timestamp) Year,
    MONTH(t1.timestamp) Month,
    CONVERT(
        varchar(12), 
        DATEADD(minute, SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp)), 0), 
        114
    ) TotalHours
FROM
    mytable t1
    INNER JOIN mytable t2 
        ON  t1.empid = t2.empid
        AND t2.read_id = 2
        AND t2.timestamp = (
            SELECT MIN(timestamp) 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE 
                read_id = 2 
                AND empid = t2.empid 
                AND timestamp > t1.timestamp
        )
WHERE 
    t1.read_id = 1 
GROUP BY t1.empid, t1.department, YEAR(t1.timestamp), MONTH(t1.timestamp)
ORDER BY  1, 2, 3, 4
```

Returns :

```
 empid | department | Year | Month | TotalHours  
 ----: | :--------- | ---: | ----: | :-----------
  3221 | IT         | 2017 |     1 | 15:24:00:000
  5565 | IT         | 2017 |     1 | 02:00:00:000
```

**[DB Fiddle demo on SQL Server 2014](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=43e4d7c14f36da0329820c241f477f4e)**

---

There is an edge case, however, where an employee enters twice and then exists (this happens in your data, where employee `5565` enters at `29/01/2017 12:28:06` *and* at `29/01/2017 12:28:07`, and then exits at `29/01/2017 13:28:06`. The above query will take in account the two overlaping entries and map them to the same exit, resulting in this hour of work being counted twice.

While this matches your expected results, is this what you really want ? Here is an alternative query that , if several consecutive of the same employee entries happen, only takes in account the latest one :

```
SELECT
    t1.empid, 
    t1.department, 
    YEAR(t1.timestamp) Year,
    MONTH(t1.timestamp) Month,
    CONVERT(
        varchar(12), 
        DATEADD(minute, SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp)), 0), 
        114
    ) TotalHours
FROM
    mytable t1
    INNER JOIN mytable t2 
        ON  t1.empid = t2.empid
        AND t2.read_id = 2
        AND t2.timestamp = (
            SELECT MIN(timestamp) 
            FROM mytable 
            WHERE 
                read_id = 2 
                AND empid = t2.empid 
                AND timestamp > t1.timestamp
        )
WHERE 
    t1.read_id = 1 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM mytable 
        WHERE 
            read_id = 1 
            AND empid = t1.empid 
            AND timestamp > t1.timestamp 
            AND timestamp < t2.timestamp
    ) 
GROUP BY t1.empid, t1.department, YEAR(t1.timestamp), MONTH(t1.timestamp)
ORDER BY  1, 2, 3, 4
```

Returns :

```
 empid | department | Year | Month | TotalHours  
 ----: | :--------- | ---: | ----: | :-----------
  3221 | IT         | 2017 |     1 | 15:24:00:000
  5565 | IT         | 2017 |     1 | 01:00:00:000
```

**[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5d313230ae3838dfffe14ad23e497514)**